# Chilli dont disconnect the client sessions with freeradius

Tags: freeradius, disconnect

I use two counter in my freeradius:

The "normal" Expire-After-Initial-Login and the Total-Max-Octets:

```
sqlcounter foreverbitscounter {
              counter-name = Total-Max-Octets
              check-name = ChilliSpot-Max-Total-Octets
              reply-name = ChilliSpot-Max-Total-Octets
              sqlmod-inst = sql
              key = User-Name
              reset = never
query = "SELECT (SUM(AcctInputOctets)+-SUM(AcctOutputOctets)) FROM radacct
WHERE UserName='%{%k}'"
}
```

The Counter works fine if I manually logoff from hotspot and connect again. But if the Client stay online the ongoing session don't get disconnected.

For Example:
`Expire-After := 3600 Seconds`

The Client can be online until he shutdown his PC, or disconnect the WLAN (or something else).

But if I disconnect with `10.1.0.1:3990`, logoff and reconnect after 3601 it works and I can't reconnect with the same tickets.